# checking list contains string

Tags: c#, json, linq

have a class that is going to be used for the remote validation function but can't get it working

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string Forename)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> user = new List<SelectListItem>();
    using (EIPInternalEntities ctx = new EIPInternalEntities())
    {
        user = new SelectList(ctx.Database
                                 .SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.uspGetLkUpJobTitle")
                                 .ToList());
    }

    var userlist = user.ToList();

    //return Json(user == null);
    return Json(!userlist.Contains(Forename));
}
```

tried different ways but currently the (Forename)) is being flagged as an error with

> "Argument 1 cannot be converted from 'string' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'

if I try

```
var userlist = (SelectList)user;

//return Json(user == null);
return Json(!userlist.Contains(Forename));
```

then the `!userList`. gets flagged saying

> SelectList does not contain a definition for Contains

Comment: Why are you using `SelectList` in the first place? Use a regular `List<T>`

Comment: Hi thanks, can you expand on that a bit please? I'm pretty new to c' and mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
return Json(!userlist.Any(x => x.Text == Forename));
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks! did try the .Any but couldn't get it working must have needed the x => x.text part.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this one:

```
!userlist.Any(item => item.Text == Forename);
```

The `userlist` is a list of `SelectListItem` objects. Each `SelectListItem` has three properties, `Name`, `Value` and `Selected`. I think it's clear that you want to look for the `Text`. If you want to look for the value, just rewrite the above using `item.Value`

Comment: typo in here `x.Text == Forename`

Comment: @stefankmitph thank you very much for spotting this.

Comment: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type "SelectListItem" because it is not a delegate type.  the below fixed the issue though, thanks

Comment: You welcome but I don't get you. Did you try the above and it didn't work. What you corrected and it ran, in case of this is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: yep both give an error with the lambda conversion.  The Answer from stefankmitph worked though I was adding in case you looked further into it :)

Comment: My fault...:( The correct version is with `Any` not with `Contains`, since `Any` can take a predicate, a function that return true/false for a given input, while `Contains` looks for a specific object if it contained in the sequence or not. Thank you !